# Updating Listbox containing tuples

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tuples

So I am creating a program that reads in input from wireless switches connected to a raspberry pi. I have them put into a listbox (because i will need to put this on a small screen later) as the switch is pressed in (inserts: 35cb 0) and then as it is pressed out it will delete that previous input and replace it (inserts: 35cb 1). I have 3 switches connected all with different ID's i.e. first four numbers/letters. I'm trying to iterate throught the listbox data and compare it with current list_of_switches (switch pressed/activated) to see if its on the list and if so i just replace it with same ID and different number (from 35cb 0 to 35cb 1)
Ive got the first switch all working but for any other switch pressed it keeps adding it to the list and not replacing itself if it is released/pressed again. My element 3 and 4 wont change based on switch input only the first two elements will update. Im sure this is an easy fix but i cant seem to figure it out.

```
def mainLoop():



        
        switches = switch_collector.items()
        
        type(switches)
        
        list_of_switches = list(switches)
        
        while True:
            
            list_range = len(list_of_switches)
            
            offset = 0
            
            while offset < list_range:
                
                pickle_out = open("Switch_Collector.txt", "wb")
                
                pickle.dump(list_of_switches, pickle_out)
                
                pickle_out.close()
                list_of_switches = list(list_of_switches)
                

                if listbox.size() == 0:
                        listbox.insert(END, list_of_switches)
                for index, tuple in enumerate(list_of_switches):
                        listboxdata = list(listbox.get(index))
                        element_one = tuple[0]
                        element_two = tuple[1]
                for index, tuple in enumerate(listboxdata):
                       #element_three = tuple[0]
                       #element_four = tuple[1]
                        while index <= listbox.size():
                                element_three = tuple[0]
                                element_four = tuple[1]
                                if element_one == element_three:
                                        listbox.delete(index)
                                        listbox.insert(index, list_of_switches)
                                        break
                                elif element_one != element_three:
                                        listbox.insert(END, list_of_switches)
                                        break
                listbox.pack(pady=10)
                
                    offset += 1
                
               
                if offset >= list_range:
               
                    break


root.after(10, mainLoop)
```

mainLoop()

root.mainloop()

Comment: Need Display (listbox) to update like so: 35cb 0 , 24lv 0, 72hc 1 <-TO-> 35cb 1, 24lv 0, 72hc 0 / when switches are flipped and adding another line when a new switch is triggered (each switch has its own line its not side by side

Comment: Could you please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve]? If the question is about updating a listbox containing tuples, we don't need much more than a listbox, some data, and the code you want to use to update the listbox.

Comment: You can [edit] this question, you don't need to create a new question.

Comment: Why is there code that is commented out? If it's not useful for reproducing the problem then you should just remove it instead of commenting it out.

Comment: @BryanOakley im very close now i rephrased the question and replaced the code with what i currently have

Comment: We can't use the posted code to reproduce the problem. For one, the code you posted doesn't create a listbox, nor does it contain any sample data.

Comment: Im aware of that the way im gettting the info for the list_of_switches is through from switches connected to a raspberry pi so you wouldnt be able to get that anyway. Is there something else i could do? my listbox creation is in the top of my code and theres a bunch of other code i left out of this because its pretty much useless unless youre using a raspberry pi to get the data. Saying that theres probably not a way to get help is there? @BryanOakley

Comment: _"Im aware of that the way im gettting the info for the list_of_switches is through from switches connected to a raspberry pi so you wouldnt be able to get that anyway. Is there something else i could do?"_ - since the problem isn't with the pi, all we need is some hard-coded data.